# Dynamic ajax call using jquery in sequence

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When I click on 'button pg1' it should show 'button pg2'. When I click on 'button pg2' it should show 'button pg3' and so on.... But it's not working in my way. Please help.... 
 **HTML code**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="display"></div>
    <button id="pg1">button pg1</button>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on( "click", "#pg1", function( event ) {
                $("#pg1").hide();
                $.post("show.php",
                {
                    id: "pg2"
                },
                function(data,status){
                    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = data;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**show.php page code**

```
<?php
    $id=$_REQUEST["id"];
    echo "
        <button id='$id'>button $id</button>
        ";
    $id = str_replace("pg", "", $id);
    $nxId = $id+1;
    echo "
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on( 'click', '#pg$id', function( event ) {
                $.post('show.php',
                {
                    id: 'pg$nxId'
                },
                function(data,status){
                    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = data;
                });
            });
        });
    </script> ";
?>
```

Comment: is the php page supposed to be a duplicate of the HTML?

Comment: yes, ajax call from html page is sent to show.php and the button is to be replaced as well as the script file should be changed according to the button for the next ajax call.

Comment: Because you seem to be missing `$("#pg1").hide();` in the php file if it's supposed to be the same

Comment: I don't need `#pg1` afterwards. I get `button pg2` when I click on `button pg1`. then it stops working.....